# Magento ProductController append categoryId to products

Tags: php, magento

I am adding a mass action to add a category. I am most of the way there I only have one function left to figure out.

Clr\Categorymassaction\controllers\Adminhtml\Catalog\ProductController.php

```
    class Clr_Categorymassaction_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
    {
        public function massCategoryAction()
        {
            $productIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
            $cat = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Category');
            if (!is_array($productIds)) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Please select product(s).'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
            }
            else {
                    $cat = $category['label']->getCategoryId();
                    foreach($productIds as $product) {
                        //Process $cat into categoryId append categoryId to $productId
                       $cat->setPostedProducts($product);

                    }
              //Save product
              $cat->save();
            }



}
}
```

Clr\Categorymassaction\Model\Observer

```
class Clr_Categorymassaction_Model_Observer {
    public function addCategoryMassAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer ->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid) {
            $block->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('Clr_Categorymassaction', array(
                'label'     =>  Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add to Category'),
                'url'       =>  $block->getUrl('*/*/massCategory', array('_current' => true)),
                'additional'=> array(
                    'visibility'    => array(
                        'name'          =>'Category',
                        'class'         =>'required-entry',
                        'label'         =>Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories'),
                        'type'          => 'select',
                        'values'        => Mage::getModel('Categorymassaction/system_config_source_category')->toOptionArray(),
                        'renderer'      => 'Categorymassaction/catalog_product_grid_render_category',

                        )
                    )
                ));
        };
    }


}
```

One last thing

```
 class Clr_Categorymassaction_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
    {
        public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
        {
            $options = array();
            foreach ($this->load_tree() as $category) {
                $options[$category['value']] =  $category['label'];
            }

            return $options;
        }
```

I am mostly in trouble here because I am refactoring, Flagbit_changeattributeset and Vuleticd_AdminGridCategoryFilter. I know what I need to do (at least I think I do) I just don't know how to finish this off. Thanks for your eyes and ears if you read it all.

UPDATE: The observer from Vuleticd_AdminGridCategoryFilter had this additional code

```
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterCallback'),
                    )
                )
            ));
    };
}
public function filterCallback($collection, $column)
{
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($value);
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($_category);

    return $collection;
}
```

This was used to apply the filter to the grid. What I am trying to do is instead of using the dropdown to filter column fields; use the dropdown to trigger the ProductController to pass the selected items a new categoryid.

Comment: What is your expected behavior? Please be specific.

Comment: So far I have added the forms in working order on the manage product screen, I select 'add a category' from the mass action dropdown and I get another dropdown with all my categories. What I don't have is the logic to add the category that was selected in the massaction to the products that were checked on the manage products screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67234/productcontroller-for-mass-action  Asked this question over at magento's stackexchange figured I would post the link here for posterity.